# Get A JSObject From A JSValue In Awesomium.NET

Tags: javascript, .net, awesomium, jsobject

From this [page](http://wiki.awesomium.com/general-use/introduction-to-javascript-integration.html) I can see how to get a `JSObject` from a `JSValue` in C++.  Is there a similar way to do so in .NET?  The `ToObject()` method doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the argument from a `JSValue` to `JSObject`

```cs
protected virtual void MyBoundMethod(object sender, JavascriptMethodEventArgs e)
{
    JSObject temp;
    JSValue value;

    if (e.Arguments == null || e.Arguments.Length == 0)
        return;

    if (JSValue.Null != e.Arguments[0] && e.Arguments[0].IsObject)
    {
       temp = (JSObject)e.Arguments[0];
       value = temp["someProperty"];
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you do not know the name of the property?

Comment: See [Awesomium::JSObject Class Reference](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_7_0/cpp_api/class_awesomium_1_1_j_s_object.html).  Try `GetMethodNames` or `HasProperty` or `HasMethod`.

Comment: Your link points to the C++ API. How can I find out the property name with HasProperty? Test for all possible variable names? I just found [this](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_GetPropertyNames.htm) but unfortunatly this yields an InvalidOperation exception.

Comment: The Awesomium API is similar between C++ and .Net.  See http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_JSObject.htm .  Confirm your version of Awesomium supports these methods if you are not using the latest bits.

Comment: I found it. But as I just said, I think I can only find the property names by calling 'myJSObject.GetPropertyNames()' but this yields an InvalidOperation exception.